# Gitlab NPM Registry Install 503

Tags: npm, gitlab, yarnpkg

I have published a package to the Gitlab NPM registry and now I am attempting to install the package into another project.

When I run in terminal:
`yarn add @org-name/project` or `npm i @org-name/project`

I get (4x):
`info There appears to be trouble with the npm registry (returned undefined). Retrying…`

Then after the 4 attempts above in the terminal I get:
`ResponseError: Request failed “503 Service Unavailable”`

I have authed to Gitlab and the group as I was able to publish the package and followed each step here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry

Any ideas at all as to why I can publish but not download the same package from the same repo or any other repo??

Thank you so very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be a typo on my part.  Le sigh.